# element never gets visible for selenium python but works fine in selenium IDE

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

i've been dealing with this for a few days and now i give up with searching and trying out

i'm writing a testCase with selenium, it's about a form that is hidden and after pressing some button it gets visible (using a bootstrap function "whatever.show()"). As i'm new with selenium the first thing i tried was make the testcase with seleniumIDE where everything worked fine, then exported to pyhon file, and when i attempt to excecute the script, it breaks saying that the **element is not visible**. i tried to wait until the element gets visible but never does. the function i tried for gets visible was

```
 try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email"))
            )
        finally:
            driver.quit()
```

there's something else, they have another panel with a input with id="Email" inside of it, but i tried to first get the panel to find the element, after clicked the button no panel gets visible for selenium despite when it's running i can see the panel visible after clicked the button

```
    terceroPanel = driver.find_element_by_id("divFormTercero")


    argosPanel = driver.find_element_by_id("divFormArgos")
    emailInput = argosPanel.find_element_by_id("Email")
    print(terceroPanel.is_displayed())
    print(argosPanel.is_displayed())
    print(emailInput.is_displayed())
    emailInput.clear()
    emailInput.send_keys("andresmauriciogomezr@gmail.com")
```

argosPanel is the panel of my interest, terceroPanel is the other one, the three console output are "False"

the complete code i tried last was

```
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/IngresosOnline/")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#btnUserArgos").click()
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email"))
        )
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    terceroPanel = driver.find_element_by_id("divFormTercero")
    argosPanel = driver.find_element_by_id("divFormArgos")
    emailInput = argosPanel.find_element_by_id("Email")
    print(terceroPanel.is_displayed())
    print(argosPanel.is_displayed())
    print(emailInput.is_displayed())
    emailInput.clear()
    emailInput.send_keys("andresmauriciogomezr@gmail.com")
```

it breaks when send the keys. even i could see the input getting focus before throw the exception

Thanks a lot if someone can give me a hand with this.

here the HTML, the code is not mine, i'm testing the app of some partners

```
div class="col-md-12" id="divFormArgos" hidden>

<section id="loginFormArgos">
    <form action="/IngresosOnline/Account/Login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CwUxjXIIsx9b0IXeDhdb7FXlhTiMuYusRMvjZjG2KIXFfSi8lhC_4j19OXZKzU8bfffxY5d_1cmzigNUCcd78AJDf7_DZXGmhnQ_ayWWWks1" />                            <h4>Use una cuenta Argos para iniciar sesión.</h4>
    <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Correo electr&#243;nico</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="El campo Correo electrónico no es una dirección de correo electrónico válida." data-val-required="El campo Correo electrónico es obligatorio." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Password">Contrase&#241;a</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Contraseña es obligatorio." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo ¿Recordar cuenta? es obligatorio." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    <label for="RememberMe">&#191;Recordar cuenta?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btnCancelar1">Cancelar</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br />
    </form> 
    </section>
```

Use una cuenta asignada para iniciar sesión.

---

Correo electrónico
            
                
                
            
        
        
            Contraseña
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                    ¿Recordar cuenta?
                
            
        
        
            
                
                Cancelar

[¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?](/IngresosOnline/Account/ForgotPassword)

Use una cuenta asignada para iniciar sesión.

---

Correo electrónico
            
                
                
            
        
        
            Contraseña
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                    ¿Recordar cuenta?
                
            
        
        
            
                
                Cancelar

[¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?](/IngresosOnline/Account/ForgotPassword)

Comment: Can you update the Question with some `HTML`?

Comment: It's possible that the website does some cheeky stuff after displaying the Submit button, like hiding it under another element so that you have to physically click it somewhere on it's displayed region to be able to log in. You could try playing with ActionChains: wait for it to be visible, then inside an ActionChain, move_to_element(), click(), clear() then send_keys and finally perform.

Comment: the thing is that it never get visible for selenium, but the strangest thing is that it works on selenium-ide

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have the same issue, all problem is that exists two elements with the same id, the first invisible and the secound (the wanted one) was visible. Selenium tried to locate the ivisible one (first)